# Difficulty in selecting tabs

Tags: c#, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-tabs

I have two tabs, one showing my macros together and sent another to show.
Macros together already selected by *default* and `Page Load` has the method that loads the corresponding data in the same

When I click on the tab of her sent macros call my method, but the tab is selected the tab is macro together.

What can it be?

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist" id="myTab">
    <li class="active"><a href="#home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Macros juntas</a></li>
    <li><a href="#enviadas" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" runat="server" onload="CarregarMacrosEnviadas">Macros enviadas </a></li>
    <li><a href="#profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Avançado</a></li>
</ul>
```

**when you click the Macros tab Sent longer call my method, instead of giving the *onload***

Comment: When I pop your markup in to Bootply, your tabs load just fine, and switch properly when they're clicked, so I'm not sure what your problem is. http://www.bootply.com/NNB1rV8q6v

Comment: on my page I have CarregarMacrosEnviadas médodo, but when you click the tab MacrosEnviadas my method is not called.

Comment: How do I call a method inside the <li> tag ??

Comment: You would likely need to write a bit of JavaScript that calls a method when a certain action is performed on a particular `<li>`.